# Would this the right place to ask questions about authoring on Verse.com?

Tags: discussion

Verse.com is a platform for editing video/multimedia stories. It enables embedding links in a story can take viewers to other parts of the story. The authoring/editing environment is a bit tricky for novices. Is this the right SE to use for asking questions about using the Verse platform, or is there a better SE for that type of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. If these projects/products are part of the ecosystem of video production, then absolutely we should encourage technical support questions in the use of these products on *this* site.

This should be a big growth area in a subject like this. The users and developers of these projects often have large communities of their own, and if someone is searching for an answer about how to use these products, I sure would like them to find ***this*** site.

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Exchange to support their community. If one of their users should end up here, you should support them and encourage more like it. The only caveat is that customer support issue like billing, bug reports, feature suggestions, and future-direction discussions should still be hosted on the company's website itself. **Stack Exchange works really well for *technical support*** as long as the company is not trying to outsource their entire customer-support channel to this site.

Comment: Thank you both. Here's an example of the type of question I had in mind: https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/verse-if-i-create-a-hotspot-link-to-a-nested-chapter-does-the-story-return-to/1504#1504

Comment: Verse has its own Support Staff and webpage.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there will be Verse questions that could be in scope, however I can also envisage some that will be programmatical so may be better on SuperUser. There may also be some that are pure support questions that would sit better on a Verse support forum.